# Default tabs in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs

I'm trying to load a default tab in the tabbed ajax code that I've got, this is the source from the head tags

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.hastiefitness.com.au/wp-content/themes/hastie/jquery.fwd_tabs.js"></script>
```

And this is what I'm using in HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-menu">
        <li><a href="#tab-1">TEAM TRAINING PROGRAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">VIRTUAL EDUCATION AND COACHING PROGRAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">PERSONAL COACHING PROGRAM</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-1">
```

**The page in question is :**

http://www.hastiefitness.com.au/programs/

The default tab is meant to be the middle one, which is tab-2.

How would I be able to perform this? I've searched and haven't been able to get it working at all.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What should default do? Should it look different? Is some sort of an activity suppose to happen? What is that js you're referencing suppose to do? What is the tab suppose to do?

Comment: The default should be the middle tab so "Virtual education and coaching program" I just want that to be the first thing that loads when the user gets to this page, and not the first tab which is what it's defaulting to.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the plugin used does not have any direct support for setting active tab so once the plugin is initialized trigger a click event on the desired anchor element

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.tabs').fwd_tabs();
    $('.tabs a[href="#tab-2"]').click()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cn5sf/)

Comment: I've just tested it and it goes to the third tab and doesn't show content. This can be seen live at the given page; http://www.hastiefitness.com.au/programs/

I also updated http://jsfiddle.net/Cn5sf/2/ with how it is from my end but it seems fine on the test, but not on my end?

Comment: @user3321286 where is the script added? in which file

Comment: I don't see the script anywhere in the page

Comment: I added it here: http://www.hastiefitness.com.au/wp-content/themes/hastie/jquery.fwd_tabs.js

Comment: I've removed it temporarily as it's affecting the clients viewing of that page.

Comment: @user3321286 when I ran the script `$('.tabs a[href="#tab-2"]').click()` in the browser console it is working fine

Comment: did you add the script after the plugin initialization using `$('.tabs').fwd_tabs()`

Comment: @user3321286 what was the problem